# sbt - object apache is not a member of package org

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I want to deploy and submit a spark program using sbt but its throwing error.

**Code:**

```
package in.goai.spark

import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}

object SparkMeApp {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("First Spark")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val fileName = args(0)
    val lines = sc.textFile(fileName).cache
    val c = lines.count
    println(s"There are $c lines in $fileName")
  }
}
```

**build.sbt**

```
    name := "First Spark"

    version := "1.0"

    organization := "in.goai"

    scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

    libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.6.1"

    resolvers += Resolver.mavenLocal
```

Under first/project directory

**build.properties**

```
bt.version=0.13.9
```

When I am trying to run `sbt package` its throwing error given below.

```
[root@hadoop first]# sbt package
[info] Loading project definition from /home/training/workspace_spark/first/project
[info] Set current project to First Spark (in build file:/home/training/workspace_spark/first/)
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/training/workspace_spark/first/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[error] /home/training/workspace_spark/first/src/main/scala/LineCount.scala:3: object apache is not a member of package org
[error] import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}
[error]            ^
[error] /home/training/workspace_spark/first/src/main/scala/LineCount.scala:9: not found: type SparkConf
[error]      val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("First Spark")
[error]                     ^
[error] /home/training/workspace_spark/first/src/main/scala/LineCount.scala:11: not found: type SparkContext
[error]      val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
[error]                   ^
[error] three errors found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 4 s, completed May 10, 2018 4:05:10 PM
```

I have tried with `extends` to `App` too but no change.

Comment: try `sbt clean package`

Answer (score 3):

Please remove `resolvers += Resolver.mavenLocal` from `build.sbt`. Since `spark-core` is available on Maven, we don't need to use local resolvers.

After that, you can try `sbt clean package`.

Comment: @BhaskarDas Are you able to run `spark-shell`?

Comment: Nope! Just the Spark Distribution - https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/spark/spark-2.3.0/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz or https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/spark/spark-2.3.0/spark-2.3.0.tgz

Comment: You didn't get my point. I am able to run spark-shell but I have to deploy the above program to submit the spark job.

Comment: Ok! Got it. Then mark the `spark-core` dependency as `provided`. Like this - `"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.6.1" % "provided"`. Then try `sbt clean package`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170840/discussion-between-himanshuiiitian-and-bhaskar-das).