# Maven build ERROR (Scala + Spark):object apache is not a member of package org

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, log4j

I read several threads about this problem on StackOverflow and other resources ([1st](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28269836/scalac-compile-yields-object-apache-is-not-a-member-of-package-org), [2nd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29515947/scala-console-error-object-apache-is-not-a-member-of-package-org), [3rd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50284764/sbt-object-apache-is-not-a-member-of-package-org)), but unfortunately it doesn't help. 
Also almost all of them describes the same problem on SBT, not Maven.

I also checked the Scala/Spark compatibility in Spark docs ([here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/)) and it seems like I have correct versions (Scala 2.11.8 + Spark 2.2.0)

I will describes my full workflow, because I'm not sure what information could be helpful to establish the root cause.

This is the code I'm trying to build

**pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>SparkWordCount</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SparkWordCount</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>

        <plugins>
            <!-- mixed scala/java compile -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- for fatjar -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <finalName>uber-SparkWordCount-1.0-SNAPSHOT</finalName>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>assemble-all</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**SparkWordCount.scala**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import org.apache.log4j.Level

object SparkWordCount {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)

    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName("SparkSessionZipsExample")
      .master("local")
      .getOrCreate()

    val myRdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7))
    myRdd.foreach(number => println("Lol, this is number = " + number))
  }
}
```

It works fine when I just launch the main() method:

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Lol, this is number = 1
Lol, this is number = 2
Lol, this is number = 3
Lol, this is number = 4
Lol, this is number = 5
Lol, this is number = 6
Lol, this is number = 7
```

Then I tried to use SparkSQL DataFrame:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SparkSession}
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import org.apache.log4j.Level

object SparkWordCount {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)

    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName("SparkSessionZipsExample")
      .master("local")
      .getOrCreate()

    val airports: DataFrame = spark.read.csv("C:\\Users\\Евгений\\Desktop\\DATALEARN\\airports.csv")
    airports.show()
  }
}
```

And this code throws an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger
    at SparkWordCount$.main(SparkWordCount.scala:10)
    at SparkWordCount.main(SparkWordCount.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Logger
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 2 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I'm not sure how exactly it works, but I fixed this by changing my Run Configuration and checking the checkbox "Include dependencies with Provided scope"

[image]

After this my SparkSQL code also works fine:

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
+---------+--------------------+-------------+-----+-------+--------+----------+
|      _c0|                 _c1|          _c2|  _c3|    _c4|     _c5|       _c6|
+---------+--------------------+-------------+-----+-------+--------+----------+
|IATA_CODE|             AIRPORT|         CITY|STATE|COUNTRY|LATITUDE| LONGITUDE|
|      ABE|Lehigh Valley Int...|    Allentown|   PA|    USA|40.65236| -75.44040|
|      ABI|Abilene Regional ...|      Abilene|   TX|    USA|32.41132| -99.68190|
|      ABQ|Albuquerque Inter...|  Albuquerque|   NM|    USA|35.04022|-106.60919|
|      ABR|Aberdeen Regional...|     Aberdeen|   SD|    USA|45.44906| -98.42183|
|      ABY|Southwest Georgia...|       Albany|   GA|    USA|31.53552| -84.19447|
|      ACK|Nantucket Memoria...|    Nantucket|   MA|    USA|41.25305| -70.06018|
|      ACT|Waco Regional Air...|         Waco|   TX|    USA|31.61129| -97.23052|
|      ACV|      Arcata Airport|Arcata/Eureka|   CA|    USA|40.97812|-124.10862|
|      ACY|Atlantic City Int...|Atlantic City|   NJ|    USA|39.45758| -74.57717|
|      ADK|        Adak Airport|         Adak|   AK|    USA|51.87796|-176.64603|
|      ADQ|      Kodiak Airport|       Kodiak|   AK|    USA|57.74997|-152.49386|
|      AEX|Alexandria Intern...|   Alexandria|   LA|    USA|31.32737| -92.54856|
|      AGS|Augusta Regional ...|      Augusta|   GA|    USA|33.36996| -81.96450|
|      AKN| King Salmon Airport|  King Salmon|   AK|    USA|58.67680|-156.64922|
|      ALB|Albany Internatio...|       Albany|   NY|    USA|42.74812| -73.80298|
|      ALO|Waterloo Regional...|     Waterloo|   IA|    USA|42.55708| -92.40034|
|      AMA|Rick Husband Amar...|     Amarillo|   TX|    USA|35.21937|-101.70593|
|      ANC|Ted Stevens Ancho...|    Anchorage|   AK|    USA|61.17432|-149.99619|
|      APN|Alpena County Reg...|       Alpena|   MI|    USA|45.07807| -83.56029|
+---------+--------------------+-------------+-----+-------+--------+----------+
only showing top 20 rows
```

**But when I'm trying to execute Maven "clean -> package" commands, I get several errors, and all of them
are regarding "org.apache" package:**

```
D:\Work Projects\SparkWordCount\src\main\scala\SparkWordCount.scala:3: error: object apache is not a member of package org
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SparkSession}
           ^
D:\Work Projects\SparkWordCount\src\main\scala\SparkWordCount.scala:4: error: object apache is not a member of package org
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
           ^
D:\Work Projects\SparkWordCount\src\main\scala\SparkWordCount.scala:5: error: object apache is not a member of package org
import org.apache.log4j.Level
           ^
D:\Work Projects\SparkWordCount\src\main\scala\SparkWordCount.scala:10: error: not found: value Logger
    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)
```

This is details about my environment, probably some of them will be helpful:

- I use Intellij IDEa
- Windows 10
- Java 8 installed

[image]

- Scala 2.11.8 installed and works:

[image]

- Spark 2.2.0 installed and works via spark-shell

[image]

- I downloaded WinUtils, created "bin" folder in it, copy winutils.exe for hadoop_2.7.1 and paste it into "bin":

[image]

- This is my HADOOP_HOME and JAVA_HOME environment variables:

[image]

- I also set SPARK2_HOME environment variable (not sure that I actually needed to do this):

[image]

- And this is my Path :

[image]

Previoulsy I've had HADOOP_HOME in Path, but I removed it on advice from one of related threads on StackOverflow.

Thank you in advance for your help!

**UPDATE-1** My project structure:

[image]

**UPDATE-2**

If it's important: I don't have MAVEN_HOME environment variable, and therefore there is no MAVEN_HOME in my Path. I executed "clean -> package" via Intellij IDEa Maven interface.

**UPDATE-3**

List of libraries from Project Structure

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**Update-4** 
Information about scala-sdk:
[image]

Comment: also can you post your project structure image ??

Comment: @Srinivas Sure, updated

Comment: go to file -> project structure -> click on libraries . show image of this ??

Comment: sorry not this.. go to file top bar -> Project structure -> Project settings -> Libraries

Comment: your scala libraries are having different version, can you try to add same versions

Comment: Can you scroll down in last image & check what version of scala-sdk do you have ?

Comment: @Srinivas I see "scala-sdk-2.11.8" in File -> Project Structure -> Platform Settings -> Global Libraries

Comment: if you see last image scala-compiler , scala-library & scala-reflect versions are different ??

Comment: @Srinivas question updated with screenshot

Comment: Idea/feeling: I have a bad feeling this is because of the fat jar setup. Could you try and compile without it?

Comment: @SašaZejnilović I tried to comment maven-assembly plugin from pom-xml, and execute "clean->package". Same error. Then I tried to execute "jar:jar" command from maven-jar-plugin, and this build was successfull

Comment: Also, your `maven-compiler-plugin` is set to 1.7. Is that even supported? Shouldn't it be 1.8?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `<scope>provided</scope>` from pom.xml file. Go to `file` tab click on `Invalidate Caches / Restart` option & Try again.

For maven issue - try `mvn clean scala:compile -DdisplayCmd=true -DrecompileMode=all package` command.

Comment: I tried to remove it from both spark-core and spark-sql dependencies. Exactly the same result

Comment: also change this - ```fully.qualified.MainClass``` to actual main class

Comment: I create package com.jd2050.example and move my class SparkWordCount.scala there. 

`<mainClass>com.jd2050.example.SparkWordCount</mainClass>`

Then I created Maven Run Configuration in Intellij interface:

`clean scala:compile -DdisplayCmd=true -DrecompileMode=all package`

I also did "Invalidate cache and Restart" couple of times. 
Same result:(